# Ternary expression always true - not NULL

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a html table, bounded with Knockout: (Just a part of the table for example)

```
<tbody>
  <!-- ko foreach: users -->
       <tr><td valign="top"><span data-bind="text: name ? name : '&nbsp;'"></span></td></tr>
  <!-- /ko -->
</tbody>
```

The problem is that the ternary expression is not working properly, it is always acting like `name` is not `NULL`, even if it is `NULL`, the first part is always executing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should be noted that that's a ternary expression, not an if statement.

Comment: Note your &nbsp is missing a semi-colon, it should be '&nbsp;'

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you very much, that was the case, I don't know how I could missed it.. Would you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `name` is an observable, it will never be falsy; you'd have to call it: `text: name() ? name() : '&nbsp;'`. KO only automatically calls them for you if they aren't part of an expression. If `name` isn't an observable, the binding won't be reevaluated if you change it.

Also note you can avoid calling it twice by using [JavaScript's curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)*: `text: name() || '&nbsp;'`.

---

* *(That's a post on my anemic little blog.)*

Comment: Thanks so much! That was the case! Thank you for the great explanation and idea!!